# Is there a way to convert MPLAB X program to Intel HEX?

Tags: microcontroller

I want to convert the C program i wrote to Intel HEX and then use a program like PonyProg, icprog or WinPic8000 to program the microcontroller. MPLAB X doesn't support my programmer. I need to program just one microcontroller once or few times and currently i don't plan to buy a programmer that MPLAB supports. It's cheap but if there is a way to do what i'm asking then i wouldn't need it. I guess it's not possible but i want to be sure. There's nothing on Google about this subject.

Answer (score 1):

On my system the hex file is saved in this directory for a typical XC16 project:

C:\PIC\PIC24\24F04KA200\Flasher (C)\test.X\dist\default\production

Comment: Unfortunatelly it gives me an error when i try to program the device. There's a problem with the file contents. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: It look like a standard Intel hex file.

Comment: Yes, definetely.